# Order By with Parameters (Query Builder)

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I am trying to make a query with using Laravel's Query Builder:

```
<?php

$sql = Model::where('idLanguage',1)
    ->orderBy(function($query) use ($filter) {
    $filter['idRegion'] === 1 ? $query->orderBy('anyField','asc') : null;
    $filter['idRegion'] === 0 ? $query->orderBy('otherField','asc'): null;
})
```

However, it does not work. Somebody, please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the code with the following:

```
if($filter['idRegion']) {
   $query->orderBy('anyField','asc');
} else {
   $query->orderBy('otherField','asc');
}
```

Comment: I meant to change the code within the callback function, which is within the `orderBy`. You should use `$query` there. But don't use ternary operator as you do, because you are not trying to return a value but rather filter the results.

Comment: I just noticed the parameter that you are passing is `$filters` plural and use `$filter` as singular in the body of the callback. Try changing that it should work.
Or just share what error you are getting.